# Script to automatically update hyperlink when a new tab in another workbook is created

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a current Google Sheet that has a bunch of hyperlinks that redirects to different Google Sheets (different workbooks). The problem I face currently is that I have to manually update the hyperlinks each week. The way it works is that the other sheets that I hyperlink to has a script which creates a new tab every new week. On my sheet, I would need to update the hyperlink each week. I was wondering if there is a script that can automate this instead of me manually update this. This wouldn't be a problem if the ending of the sheet URL followed a pattern instead of being randomly generated for each new tab.

There are a bunch of "hyperlink to a certain sheet or a cell of a certain sheet" but all of these refer to the sheet being in the same workbook as the sheet where they need the hyperlink in. My problem is with 2 different sheets/workbook.

Is it possible for there to be a script where it can take the hyperlink function and change/update it each week when a new tab in another workbook is created?

ex.

A1= hyperlink("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/.../edit#gid=0","Sales")

Next week it updates to

A1= hyperlink("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/.../edit#gid=1","Sales")

I know gid=1 is not correct but I am just using it as an example to say that the UR: has been updated to the new tab's URL.

Comment: Yes, you can update the script that generates the new tab to open the workbook with hyperlinks and update the relevant cell. That random number is referred to as the worksheets "sheet ID" or "grid ID", and yes, it is programmatically accessible. If you can't modify the sheet-creating script, you can create a new script that stores known sheet IDs and then updates the hyperlink when a new sheet ID is found.

Comment: Hey thanks that may work. I will give it a try and see what I can do.